# Can't get my Google Maps supportMapFragment to have layout width/height to "match_parent"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I can't seem to get my Google Maps to stay at "match_parent" in layout width/height.

The following is how I want it to stay:

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.myname.myapp.MapsActivity" >

<fragment

    android:id="@+id/map"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

As soon as I click "preview" or "design" in Android Studio text, the following happens:

```
<fragment

    android:id="@+id/map"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="395dp"
    android:layout_height="643dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
```

The code just transforms into the above, and I don't need this. This above code doesn't fit the entire screen, there's a lot of white space on all corners left. It looks like the following:

[image]

Even if I constraint the view to the screen, this is as big as it gets, so there will still be this white space on all sides.

How do I make it "match_parent" on layout_width and layout_height without it "fixing" itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving the following layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.example.myname.myapp.MapsActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: it tells me "unknown attribute app"

Comment: no, for some reason   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" gives me error saying "Namespace declaration is never used". You think this has something to do with it?

Comment: Are you sure that you copied the layout exactly?